# Can't stop browser from caching data for Django app

Tags: django, google-chrome, caching, view

I have a Django form in one of my templates that is just a bunch of checkboxes and labels for the items that you are choosing. I have a function that gets the price of that item in the backend when its checked, and returns a grand total which is inserted into the front end. When I submit the form and go to the next page, it adds all the items that you checked to be true to a cart that is stored in a session. Even after deleting the items from the cart on that checkout page, when I go back a page, the grand total is still on the page even though none of the checkboxes are checked. If I clear my browsers cache on the checkout page, before going back a page everything is cleared out like it should be.

I tried using Django's @never_cache decorator on the view function that gets hit when going back a page, but it doesn't work. I am using Django 1.7.5 so I manually added extra values to the Cache-Control header that the never_cache decorator uses, because no-cache, no-store, and must-revalidate aren't values that get passed into the header in Django versions under 1.9.

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
```

Here is PyCharm showing all the headers of the http response object

[image]